# onCreateView() method of ViewPager's childFragment not being called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

 static MyListfragment mf;
 ViewPager mpager;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        mf = new MyListfragment();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content,mf).commit();
}}
```

**MyListfragment.java**

```
public class MyListfragment extends SherlockListFragment {

MyDisplayfragment tempFrag;
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Connector.selection = position;
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if(position==0)
        {
        tempFrag=new MyDisplayfragment();
        tempFrag.setLayout(R.layout.law);
        subFragmentAdapter mAdapter = new subFragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        tempFrag.setViewPagerAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    ft.replace(android.R.id.content,tempFrag);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            layout, Connector.list));
}}
```

**MyDisplayfragment.java**

```
public class MyDisplayfragment extends SherlockFragment {

int resource;
FragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;
ViewPager v;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(Connector.selection==-1)
        resource=R.layout.displayfragment;
    return inflater.inflate(resource, container, false);
}

public void setViewPagerAdapter(FragmentPagerAdapter x)
{
    mAdapter=x;
}

public void setLayout(int layout)
{
    resource=layout;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ViewPager pager=(ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.mpager);
    pager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}}
```

**subFragment.java**

```
public final class subFragment extends SherlockFragment {

private int layout;
public static subFragment newInstance(int content) {
    subFragment fragment = new subFragment();
    fragment.layout=content;
    return fragment;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(layout,container,false);
}}
```

**subFragmentAdapter.java**

```
public class subFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{


int[] LAYOUT={R.layout.cccc,R.layout.aaaa,R.layout.bbb};
private int mCount;

public subFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mCount = LAYOUT.length;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return subFragment.newInstance(LAYOUT[position]);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCount;
}

}
```

**Connector.java**

```
public class Connector {

static int selection = -1;
static String list[] = { "Law" };}
```

In the above project
1)MyListfragment.java is used for navigation
2)MyDisplayfragment.java is used to display according to selection made in MyListFragment
3)Connector.java is used to communicate between the above two fragments
4)subFragment.java is used to populate Viewpager with Fragments
5)subFragmentAdapter.java is th adapter for Viewpager

When i run this project the viewpager seems to be blank and doesnot show any of the child fragments and after debugging i saw that onCreateView() method of subFragment.java is not called.
My question is why the onCreateView() method is not being called

Comment: Try to use the `getChildFragmentManager()` of the newly created `MyDisplayfragment` fragment. Also, you shouldn't pass objects like you do(the adapter) when you're creating the `MyDisplayfragment` fragment, for example, you don't have any reason for creating the adapter there and not directly in `MyDisplayfragment`.

Comment: but i have used 'getChildFragmentManager()' in MyListfragment when instantiating subFragmentAdapter

Comment: @Luksprog: write your comment as the answer so that i can accept

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please refer to Luksprog's comment for the answer.